# Python reading a public google spreadsheet with no share option

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api

Can I read a google spreadsheet which is open to people, but doesn't have a `share` option? There's a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399729/python-reading-a-google-spreadsheet), but it's I need to have an authorization to click the `share` option.

Even copying by URL to my own Google spreadsheet may serve the purpose.

#### Update:

The idea was once I create a Google API, I should be able to create a .json file with a client email. In the share option, I'm supposed to provide the client email of .json file. You may see: [Accessing Google Spreadsheet Data using Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/accessing-google-spreadsheet-data-using-python-90a5bc214fd2).

This is the spreadsheet page where I'm not finding any Share option: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSc_2y5N0I67wDU38DjDh35IZSIS30rQf7_NYZhtYYGU1jJYT6_kDx4YpF-qw0LSlGsBYP8pqM_a1Pd/pubhtml#

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `a google spreadsheet which is open to people, but doesn't have a share option`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: The idea was once I create a Google API, I should be able to create a .json file with a `client email`. In the `share` option, I'm supposed to provide the client email of .json file. You may see: https://towardsdatascience.com/accessing-google-spreadsheet-data-using-python-90a5bc214fd2

Comment: Thank you for replying. From the link in your replying, I thought that you might have wanted to access the Spreadsheet using the service account. But unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your goal. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: You mean you cannot see the green `Share` button on the top right of the spreadsheet? I cannot reproduce this behaviour, it's true that the owner can forbid other people to share the spreadsheet with others, but I think the `Share` button should show up anyway. Have you tried sharing the file via Drive API, with [Permissions: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert)? Are you able to do this? Could you share the URL of a copy of this file, free of any sensitive information?

Comment: Not exactly, seems in Drive API, I need to fill up a lot of information. Can you check this? 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSc_2y5N0I67wDU38DjDh35IZSIS30rQf7_NYZhtYYGU1jJYT6_kDx4YpF-qw0LSlGsBYP8pqM_a1Pd/pubhtml#

This is the spreadsheet page where I'm not finding any `Share` option.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

Publishing the contents of a spreadsheet to the web is not the same as making a spreadsheet public.

The URL you shared refers to spreadsheet contents that were published to the web following [these steps](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965). This published website is not the same as the original file where the data comes from, and so it doesn't have most of its functionalities, like a `Share` button (it doesn't make sense to have a `Share` button anyway, since this URL is already public).

#### Solution:

If you want to access the spreadsheet data using a Service Account, you would have to do one of the following (better to use method 1 if you have access to the spreadsheet):

1. Share the spreadsheet itself (not the published contents) with the Service Account, as explained in the link you referenced.
2. Use your application to fetch the website contents from the provided URL.

#### Reference:

- [Make Google Docs, Sheets, Slides & Forms public](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965)